# PHP file_get_contents x-domain causes page-load to wait. cant it be done asynchronously somehow?

Tags: php, asynchronous, timeout, delay, file-get-contents

I need to do two things...

1. `file_get_contents` and then use it in javascript
2. `file_get_contents` and then use it in php

the loading of the source files caused a delay in the loading of my website so if the source is slow or offline it has terrible consequences.

what is a good work around or solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried caching the data from `file_get_contents` for a short time?

Comment: Look at [curl_multi_init](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) if you want to do async file downloads in PHP.  What types of files are you actually using file_get_contents to fetch?

Answer (score -1):

In javascript (with jquery) there are two way tested.
The first is by iframe:

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#youriframe").attr("src","http://yoururl");
});
```

body:

```
<iframe id="yourframe" src=""></iframe>
```

or you by ajax whit a div with id=yourcointainer

js:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'http://yoururl',                 
            type : 'GET',
            dataType : 'html',
            success: function (result) {                        
                $('#yourcointainer').html(result);
            },
            error: function(){
                $('#yourcointainer').html('request fail');
            }           
        });
    });
```

body:

```
<div id="yourcointainer"></div>
```

While in PHP i don't find a right way to take the data from the request without to wait the itself.